# Proof of subsets with $|S|$ pair is $2^{n-1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

How do I prove that the number of subsets $S$ of $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$, where $|S|$ is an even number is calculated by $2^{n-1}$, $n\ge1$

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far? Plus, it should be $2^n$

Comment: Try induction on $n$.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding, and it asks only for the subsets that have a pair number of elements or none

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "pair" in this particular problem?

Comment: You don't need to assume even cardinality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:)

We want cardinality of subsets to be even. So, we can think of it as:

(a) Selecting two elements from $n$

(b) Selecting $4$ elements from $n$

(c)Selecting $6$ elements from $n$ and so on..

And add all of the above to find a total number of such subsets.

Suppose $n$ is even: 
$\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{4} + \cdots + \binom{n}{n}  = 2^{n-1}$

Note: If $n$ is odd then last expression would be $\binom{n}{n-1}$

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the binomial theorem here.

Recall: $$(x + y)^n = \sum \limits_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{n - k}y^{k}$$

If we substitute the expression with $x = 1$ and $y = 1$, we obtain $$2^n = \sum \limits_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}$$

That's the number of all subsets of set $|S| = n$.

If you substitute  it with $x = -1$ and $y = 1$, we obtain $$0 = \sum \limits_{i = 0}^{n} (-1)^k\binom{n}{k} $$

$$ \binom{n}{0} - \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} - \binom{n}{3} + \dotso = 0 \iff\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{2} + \dotso = \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{3} 
 + \dotso$$

Therefore, you can conclude that number of subsets with even number  of elements is equal to number of subsets with odd number of elements and they are both equal to $2^{n - 1}$, as $2^{n - 1} + 2^{n - 1} = 2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach with binaries:

Denote $f$ as a image which maps each n-length binary word $ (a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ to the subset of the set $ S=\{1,2,...,n\}$ as $ \{ i  |a_i = 1 \} $, $n\ge1$.

Meaning that $f$ maps the set of n-length binary words to the set of subsets of the group $ S$.

We know that amount of n-length binary words with even amount of $1$s (or $0$:s) is $2^{n-1}$, since first $n-1$ digits have $2^{n-1}$ different ways to be chosen and last digit is either $1$ or $0$ depending of the parity.

Since the defined mapping $f$ is clearly a bijection, the number of even subsets of $S$ equals the amount of the previous binary words. So $|S|=2^{n-1}$.